# Performance : How to fix a custom checkbox component in a huge Flatlist in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have used Flatlist component of react-native to render a huge list of checkboxes 
These checkboxes (written in pure JS) essentially are mimicking the behaviour of checkboxes, everything works fine , but the performance of this is extremely slow.
What Can I do to improve the performance of this ?
the list usually renders about 1000 elements.
And here is the code:

```
<FlatList
      style={{flex:1}}
      data={finalData}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      renderItem={({item})=>{
        var iconType = (this.state.selectedItems.indexOf(item.name)>-1?"ios-checkmark-circle":"ios-checkmark-circle-outline");
        return(
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={
              ()=>{
                var selectedItems = this.state.selectedItems;
                var selectedItemsData = this.state.selectedItemsData;
                if(selectedItems.indexOf(item.name)>-1){
                  const index = selectedItems.indexOf(item.name);
                  selectedItems.splice(index, 1);
                  selectedItemsData.splice(index,1);
                }else{
                  selectedItems.push(item.name);
                  selectedItemsData.push({name:item.name,id:item.id});
                }

                this.setState({selectedItems});
                this.setState({selectedItemsData});
              }}>
            <View style={{padding:20,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'flex-start'}}>
              <Icon name={iconType} color="#45AA6F" size={25} />
              <Text style={{marginLeft:10,paddingTop:4,color:'#9B9B9B',fontWeight:'500'}}>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <Dash style={{height:1}} dashColor="#45AA6F"/>
          </TouchableOpacity>)}
      }
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using FlatList use ListView

you can use `initialListSize` to set initial list size when load so memory save there

also, you can use `scrollRenderAheadDistance` this will pre-render some elements ahead

Comment: thanks I will try that, can you share an example of it ?
what makes me wonder : is this going to take care of the performance implications that comes with re-renders after somebody make a selection of these checkboxes ?

Comment: why done you create a separate component for checkbox that handle state for each check item

Comment: Ah! that makes so much sense, I will try that today.

Comment: So making a separate component to render the checkbox behaviour did not helped with the performance , it is still sluggish. Neither did specifying the initialListSize
@Jigar

Answer (score 0):

So It appears the fix was extremely simple than I envisioned, all I needed to do was extend my component from PureComponent rather than Component.
I.e

`class cropsOnProperty extends PureComponent` 
Instead of 
`class cropsOnProperty extends Component`

Also `shouldComponentUpdate` helps in achieving the same result with far more granularity in control on when the render should happen

More can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#examples)

Comment: Hey, I'm faced with the same scenario, how are you maintaining the state of the checkbox if you're maintaining a separate list of selected items? Does each checkbox maintain its own state independent of the `selectedItems` array?